# Freemarker form status.expression in spring.ftl is undefined

Tags: spring, forms, freemarker

I am pretty new to Freemarker. I am trying to implement a dropdown list with Freemarker:

```
<@spring.formSingleSelect "signals" signals attributes=""/>
```

When I load the page I do see something resembling a dropdown box. But without any values. When I inspect down to the level of the first select field it creates I see the following error:

```
<select id=" 
Expression status.expression is undefined on line 221, column 19 in spring.ftl.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${status.expression?replace('[','')?replace(']','')} [on line 221, column 17 in spring.ftl]
 in user-directive spring.formSingleSelect [on line 124, column 29 in employeeportal.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression status.expression is undefined on line 221, column 19 in spring.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.invalidTypeException(TemplateObject.java:135)
    at freemarker.core.RegexBuiltins$replace_reBI._getAsTemplateModel(RegexBuiltins.java:251)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    etc.....
```

Also `signals` is a java Map.

I have no clue how to solve this issue. Any suggestions?
Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

use
`spring.status.expression`. In your case use `${spring.status.expression?replace('[','')?replace(']','')}`